# Which RDBMS or Data Structure I should use?

Tags: php, database, data-structures, find, rdbms

I want to build an index of the needles for performance reason.

There are hundreds of needles with very random characters from the binary files.

I need to compare a haystack against hundreds of needles. If the matching pattern found then it will need to return a needle content.

For Example

```
$haystack = "£$%^&DFFFD$%^&*("


Needles:
    1 | £"$£AAAA"£$
    2 | ((*BHJJ£$£$
    3 | ^&DFFFD$
    4 | &&&&&HUIH"£$%
```

It should return ^&**DFFFD**$% from ID 3

Which RDBMS or Data Structure I should use?

This project will be done in PHP

Comment: Create a DFA from the needles. (this is essentially what GREP does). If the needles are non-overlapping, you could even use (f)lex to generate the DFA for you.

Comment: @wildplasser I have found opensource DFA in PHP http://www.cip-labs.net/2011/05/04/deterministic-finite-automaton-in-php/ -  Looking at this example example I am confused how put needles content to DFA

Comment: Well, that is a brave exercise. I would not expect anybody to try to build a DFA in PHP. The problem is: the people that build DFA's don't do PHP, and the people who know PHP don't know how to build DFAs ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser, please stop with the generalizations. That's embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

I would go with hashing with chaining for needles.

when i get a haystack i create a list of all possibile needles ,compute it hash and compare it with the already computed needles hash values.